# Classical ASP Concurrent Insertion

Tags: asp-classic

I have an old project in classical ASP. I am having the problem that sign ups always exceeds the maximum number I have set up in the database. My code checks the current maximum seats first and then do the insertion.

The sql is like `select count(*) as cnt, sessionsize from signup`

```
 if cnt >= sessionsize then
     stop
 else
     run insert query
 end if
```

but it doesn't work properly right now. How do I solve this problem? TIA

Comment: First step, show us real code, the code you've included is not telling use enough.  What Database is the system using?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of performing a `select count(*) as cnt` everytime, to store the current value in an application var.

Sorry asp is rusty and im trying to remember this stuff. Plus I am a C# coder now.

```
if (Application("Count") = "") then
    Application.Lock()
    Application("Count") = Select count(*) ....
    Application.Unlock()
end if

if (Application("count") > sessionsize) then
    stop
else
    Application.Lock()
    Application("Count") = Application("Count") + 1
    run insert query //Place this line before the unlock
    Application.Unlock()
end if
```

Comment: thanks. can I add the applicaiton("count") code in the .asp page or do I have to create a global.asa page to store the applicaiton variable?

Comment: You should add the first if statement to the global file.